# How to make a self expanding UILabel which is inside a UIStackVIew?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, xcode8

I have an application which shows the from and drop location in the UI part. Since i have placed these to UILabels for showing the from and to location in the Stack View. Currently if the from or to location name is bigger it gets truncated at the end and it does not shows the name fully. The example image is shown below:
[image: Truncated From and To location]

Now i wish to have the From and To location to be fully shown by showing the remaining part in next line . How to achieve this? Currently i am using the following constraints:
[image: Constraints in Storyboard]

What constraints should i give so that the label expands according to content height wise. And also the stack View should also expand with it.
Please see to this and have an idea. I shall be helpful.

Following is the attributes set for the label:
[image: Attributes set]

When i tried to give the number of lines as 0 it get like this:
[image: Overlaps with under contents]

Comment: Give number of lines as 0

Comment: if you want one line resizing - read about hugging/compression resistance priorities

Comment: @AravindAR So after that the label will expand heightwise right?

Comment: @ChelseaShawra yup..

Comment: @AravindAR are my constraints Correct? I will check and let u know. If you post an answer i can mark it as accepted

Comment: @ChelseaShawra I think the constraints that you have provided is correct.

Comment: @AravindAR I tried it but it is overlapping . Please see the attached image

Comment: @ChelseaShawra give bottom constraint for the label.

Comment: @ChelseaShawra I have added the answer, it would be great if you could make further comments there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154323/discussion-between-chelsea-shawra-and-aravind-a-r).

Answer (score 0):

The number of lines that you have given for the label is 1. So it will get truncated if the content cannot fit in a single line. So if you want the label to grow vertically and show all the contents give number of lines as 0.

Comment: I have given the bottom constriants . I will check and let u know. The solution is good but it is overlapping the contents under it. If it goes i will support it.

Comment: @ChelseaShawra try giving the bottom constraint of the label to the label below it. I guess it will work

Comment: You mean Vertical spacing from salmiya to journey type?

Comment: @ChelseaShawra could you please show how you have updated the constraint ?

Comment: Please look in the chat i have updated with the screen

Comment: @ChelseaShawra could you please provide the link of chat ?
I'm not able to get it

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154323/discussion-between-chelsea-shawra-and-aravind-a-r

Comment: @ChelseaShawra please check the chat